# React Native FlatList renderItem required props and names of the props

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native and Javascript and have a question about FlatLists prop requirements and documentation, specifically the name of the prop that is fed into renderItem.  I looked at the official documentation [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist) and am playing with their first example code (which I modified and placed below).

The code does not seem to work if the prop is named anything other than "item".  I modified the first example code from the aforementioned documentation to illustrate this below. From the limited programming experience I have (in Java, Python, C), this is puzzling to me because I thought the parameters could be named anything and that the parameters is only in scope for the function it's a parameter for.  I also read several tutorials and an online class lecture on this topic and couldn't see why it has to be named "item". I see that FlatList takes the array it is given for its data prop/parameter and then feeds each element of that array as a parameter for the function I am supposed to give as the renderItem prop, but I would've thought that function can be called anything and call its own parameters anything as long as it takes them in the right order.  I put an example at the very bottom where I illustrate this in a simple javascript math situation.

My questions are:

1. Why does it matter what the props are called for the function I define and then give to FlatList to use as the renderItem parameter?
2. I trust the documentation says this somewhere, but I've read it many times and do not see it so I must not be recognizing it.  I am reading the docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#renderitem) which just seem to indicate that FlatList has a parameter named renderItem that requires a function with three of its own parameters and what each of those parameters should do.  In the docs the first happens to be named "item" but the function itself also happens to be named "renderItem" and yet as my example shows the function doesn't need to be called "renderItem".  **So how do I know which parameters, function names, or etc are magic words that need to be exactly copied and which are not?**

FlatList code:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {View, FlatList, Text,} from 'react-native';
    
    //this works
    function renderer({ item }) {                
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> {item.title} </Text>           
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    /*this does NOT work
    function renderer({ anotherName}) {                //line
      return (
        <View>
          <Text> {anotherName.title} </Text>           //line
        </View>
      );
    }
    */
    
    const App = () => {
      return (
          <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderer}
          />
      );
    };
    
    
     //I dont think anything below here is relevant
    const DATA = [
      {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'First Item',
      },
      {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'Second Item',
      },
      {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'Third Item',
      },
    ];
    
    export default App;
```

Conversely I would expect it to work like this where the name of the parameter/prop doesn't matter outside the function it's used in:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {Text} from 'react-native';
    
    function taker(a, b) {
      return (a+b)
    }
    
    function giver(x){
      return (taker(x,3))
    }
    
    export default App = () => {
      return (
          <Text>
          {giver(2)}
          </Text>
      );
    };
```

Comment: As an object is passed to the renderItem function and that object has a key 'item'. You can change the parent name i.e, you can change the name of the object but not the name of its keys as it will get confused which key to select if it has multiple keys

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  Are you saying to swapping "item" for "anyname.item" should work? I tried but it didn't work.  Can you help me recognize where in the documentation it explains what other key-value pairs are given to that object?  I had thought the object was just the element in the Data array and didn't realize there was more to it...

Comment: Also remove the curly brackets

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to JS, I will first suggest you, have a look at the destructuring concept in Javascript. In this particular case, the FlatList built-in **renderItem** function has its own parameters. If you console log the props you will get the following:

```
const renderItem = (props) => {
   console.log(props)
   const { item } = props;

   return <Item title={item.title} />
}
```

[image]

So in the example, we are just getting {item} from destructuring, if you pass any name other than **item, index, and separators** it will not work because renderItem do not know that. Hope that answers your question!